# Make a local Git repo from master based with Zend Repo as Origin

Tags: git, zend-framework, ssh, git-clone

I would like to make a clone of a master branch on the test server where we have the master branch and the test site running. This repo is a Zend PHP Framework Application. In the config file @ `/home/me/public_html/domain.com/ZendSkeletonApplication/.git/config` I have now:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication.git
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

I was considering doing my first git clone using SSH ever. I think it should be something like

`git clone me@domain.com:~/public_html/site.com/ZendSkeletonApplication/project.git`. But of course I do not want to copy the Zend framework repo, but the master branch. How do I do that using SSH? What would be the repo name?

Comment: Seems the repo does not have description yet: `cat description 
Unnamed repository; edit this file 'description' to name the repository.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url should be:

```
me@domain.com:~/public_html/domain.com/ZendSkeletonApplication
```

(assuming that you have `ssh me@domain.com` works, and that git is a known command in that ssh session)

That will clone everything, but checkout the `master` branch.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was easier than I thought.